# How to fix shading/topology issue?

Tags: shaders, topology

I'm trying to fix my low poly topology/shading issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can u share your .blend file? I guess that is happening because of that triangle in between the quads. Tris and polygons are not always good for the geometry of the mesh while you have all quads... If you share the blend file I can try cleaning up the topology of the mesh